# How to create directory using sftp in apache ant build.xml

Tags: java, apache, ant, sftp

I need help to create directory on remote server if not exists in build.xml using sftp option not scp option.

for eg below is the option I am using to upload the

If I create the directory manually and use above path then it works but I need to create directory in sftp if not exist.

TIA.

Comment: Create an empty local directory and then "upload" it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Tried to create local directory and then upload but it says not a regular file.